# Ffind field name of record that has error

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, handler

I have plsql like below:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_data IS
        SELECT t2.ID, t2.NA, t2.NAME
          FROM SABAPAY_TEMP.TEST2 t2;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c_data
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO SABAPAY_TEMP.TEST t (t.ID, t.NA, t.NAME)
                 VALUES (i.id, i.na, i.name);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
                INSERT INTO SABAPAY_TEMP.TEST5 t5 (t5.VALUE)
                     VALUES (i.na);
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

as you can see each record that has error and cant insert in table test will be insert in 'test5' table
I have a field in 'test5' that can store string.
I want to store the filed name of record that has error.
How can i find which filed is reason of error?

Comment: Could you please share the schema of SABAPAY_TEMP.TEST2 and the error you are receiving?

Comment: _Ergi Nushi
i did not get any error, i want to know that if during of insert each of record that cant insert in main table and move to second table, which field was reason of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe store error message [sqlerrm](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems050.htm) in `test5`?:

```
declare 
  cursor c_data is select id, na, name from test2; 
  v_err varchar2(1000);
begin 
  for i in c_data loop 
    begin 
      insert into test (id, na, name) values (i.id, i.na, i.name); 
    exception when others then 
      v_err := sqlerrm;
      insert into test5 (value, reason) values (i.na, v_err); 
    end; 
  end loop; 
end;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e5a71a554db7201593d3bebc700786f1)</sup>**

In my example constraint `not null` on `name` was violated and you can see it in column `reason`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DML error logging to capture most issues:

```
create table t (
  c1 int
    primary key
);

exec DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('t', 'err$_t');

insert into t 
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select level from dual
  connect by level <= 5
  log errors 
  reject limit unlimited;

select * from t;

C1   
    1 
    2 
    3 
    4 
    5 

select * from err$_t;

ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ ORA_ERR_MESG$                                                ORA_ERR_ROWID$   ORA_ERR_OPTYP$   ORA_ERR_TAG$   C1   
              1 ORA-00001: unique constraint (CHRIS.SYS_C0013611) violated   <null>           I                 <null>          1
```

So you could simplify your code to:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SABAPAY_TEMP.TEST t (t.ID, t.NA, t.NAME)
    SELECT t2.ID, t2.NA, t2.NAME
    FROM SABAPAY_TEMP.TEST2 t2
    LOG ERRORS
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
END;
/
```